# PDF report in zabbix 2.2.9

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am using Zabbix for the first time and successfully configured the same. Now the next very important step is to generate report and download as PDF. There are few links available to facilitate the same but I am unable to get the desired output.

https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24998

Please help with some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report

zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report module allow us to generate pdf reports. Once implemented we have options to generate reports for ‘Host’, ‘Host Group’ on time range of ‘Hour’, ‘Day’, ‘Week’, ‘Month’, ‘Year’.
We can retrieve old report from ‘Old Reports’ section.

#### Implementation Dependencies

- php5-curl
- php5-json

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-json`

**Clone the git repo that contain the module**

cd /opt/

git clone https://github.com/SandipSingh14/Zabbix_

**Configure zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report according to zabbix-server**

vim Zabbix_/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/config.inc.php

```
<?php
//CONFIGURABLE
# zabbix server info(user must have API access)
$z_server       = 'http://zabbix.example.com/';
$z_user      = 'admin';
$z_pass         = 'zabbix';
# Temporary directory for storing pdf data and graphs - must exist 
$z_tmp_path    = './tmp';
# Directory for storing PDF reports
$pdf_report_dir    = './report';
# Root URL to reports
$pdf_report_url    = "./report";
# paper settings
$paper_format    = 'A4'; // formats supported: 4A0, 2A0, A0 -> A10, B0   -> B10, C0 -> C10, RA0 -> RA4, SRA0 -> SRA4, LETTER, LEGAL, EXECUTIVE, FOLIO
$paper_orientation = 'portrait'; // formats supported: portrait / landscape
# time zone - see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$timezone    = 'Asia/Calcutta';
# Logo used in PDF - may be empty
# TODO: Specify image size!
$pdf_logo    = './images/zabbix.png';
$company_name   = 'Zabbix';
//DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE
$z_tmp_cookies     = "/tmp/";
$z_url_index     = $z_server ."index.php";
$z_url_graph    = $z_server ."chart2.php";
$z_url_api    = $z_server ."api_jsonrpc.php";
$z_login_data    = "name=" .$z_user ."&password=" .$z_pass ."&autologin=1&enter=Sign+in";
?>
```

#### Change directory and create directory inside zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report

cd Zabbix_/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report

mkdir tmp report

#### Change zabbix auth to login method, it’s required for login into zabbix server

```
sed -i 's,user.authenticate,user.login,g' inc/ZabbixAPI.class.php
sed -i 's,user.authenticate,user.login,g' inc/ZabbixAPI.class.php.org
```

#### Copy zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report into /usr/share/zabbix/

```
cp -r /opt/Zabbix_/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report /usr/share/zabbix/
```

#### Restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

#### Procedure to Generate Reports

Open  Generate PDF Report page

http:///zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/index.php

- Once Opened you can choose report type ‘HOST OR HOSTGROUP’ and click the dropdown to select the hostname or hostgroup name
- And you can choose report range ‘LAST OR CUSTOM’ and select the dropdown for the time period of report
- And if you select ‘custom’ in report range then you can select the time period for which you want to generate the report.
- And click on  ‘GENERATE’ button and your report will be generated.
- Module provides feature of old reports i.e you can see the reports you have generated earlier.