# PDF report Generation in Zabbix is not working

Tags: php, pdf, report, zabbix

I am trying to add pdf report generation module onto zabbix from the below repo:

https://github.com/SandipSingh14/Zabbix_

I have created tmp and report folders.
Looks like the PDF's are not getting created on the server, not sure why! Please see a snapshot of the request below:

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TPpn.jpg)

PHP Config File:

```
<?php
//CONFIGURABLE
# zabbix server info(user must have API access)
$z_server       = 'http://10.10.100.122/zabbix';
$z_user     = 'admin';
$z_pass         = 'zabbix';
# Temporary directory for storing pdf data and graphs - must exist
$z_tmp_path = '/usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/tmp';
# Directory for storing PDF reports
$pdf_report_dir = '/usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/report';
# Root URL to reports
$pdf_report_url = $z_server ."/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/report";
# paper settings
$paper_format   = 'A4'; // formats supported: 4A0, 2A0, A0 -> A10, B0 ->      B10, C0 -> C10, RA0 -> RA4, SRA0 -> SRA4, LETTER, LEGAL, EXECUTIVE, FOLIO
$paper_orientation = 'portrait'; // formats supported: portrait / landscape
# time zone - see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$timezone   = 'Asia/Calcutta';
# Logo used in PDF - may be empty
# TODO: Specify image size!
$pdf_logo   = './images/zabbix.png';
$company_name   = 'Zabbix';

//DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE
$z_tmp_cookies  = "/tmp/";
$z_url_index    = $z_server ."index.php";
$z_url_graph    = $z_server ."chart2.php";
$z_url_api  = $z_server ."api_jsonrpc.php";
$z_login_data   = "name=" .$z_user ."&password=" .$z_pass   ."&autologin=1&enter=Sign+in";
?>
```

Here is what I get when using the debug from index.php

HostID: 10153
Report Type: host
Time Period: 3600
Temp image path: /tmp/zabbix_report_OPt9cZ

```
HOSTNAME(id:10153)
CPU load(id:1289)
Memory usage(id:1290)
Disk space usage C:(id:1297)
Disk space usage E:(id:1399)
Disk space usage F:(id:1400)
Disk space usage G:(id:1401)
Report ready - available as: http://10.10.100.122/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-  report/report/HOSTNAME.pdf
```

OS: Ubuntu
Zabbix Version: 2.4.7

Here are the PHP Error logs:

```
[Mon Feb 15 21:19:47.162244 2016] [:error] [pid 29796] [client 10.10.100.108:55341] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/inc/ZabbixAPI.class.php on line 122, referer: http://10.10.100.122/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/index.php
[Mon Feb 15 21:19:47.696413 2016] [:error] [pid 29796] [client 10.10.100.108:55341] PHP Warning:  fopen(/usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/report/BLR-D-J9PSXX1.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/createpdf.php on line 319, referer: http://10.10.100.122/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/index.php
[Mon Feb 15 21:19:47.696446 2016] [:error] [pid 29796] [client 10.10.100.108:55341] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/createpdf.php on line 320, referer: http://10.10.100.122/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/index.php
[Mon Feb 15 21:19:47.696455 2016] [:error] [pid 29796] [client 10.10.100.108:55341] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/createpdf.php on line 321, referer: http://10.10.100.122/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/index.php
```

Please help me with your suggestions!

Comment: You probably need to look at the PHP error log.

Comment: @mkaatman, Hi, I have updated the PHP error logs, please see if you can help me figure the issue!

Comment: Are you using the latest version from here? https://github.com/confirm/PhpZabbixApi/releases Also, which version of PHP?

Comment: I installed PHP like this:
apt‐get install php5 php5‐cli php5‐common php5‐mysql

Do I have to use the latest version from the link you send? How do I do that? I am sorry but I am a newbie to all this!

Comment: You can find the specific PHP version using `php -v` on the command line or running the `phpinfo();` command in a script. It's very difficult to determine why your installation isn't working but my suspicion is a permission issue. What is the output of 'ls -l /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/tmp'

Comment: PHP version is 5.5.9-ubuntu4.14
Output of ls on /tmp and /report is :Total 0. I only just followed what Sandip has answered in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848650/pdf-report-in-zabbix-2-2-9?newreg=4ab7f2e191b64455b866deaf60ec00fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report

zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report module allow us to generate pdf reports. Once implemented we have options to generate reports for ‘Host’, ‘Host Group’ on time range of ‘Hour’, ‘Day’, ‘Week’, ‘Month’, ‘Year’. 
We can retrieve old report from ‘Old Reports’ section.

### Implementation

- Note: This procedure is mentioned for Ubuntu or similar os only.

#### Dependencies

- php5­curl
- php5­json

`sudo apt-­get install php5­curl php5­json`

#### Clone the git repo that contain the module

`cd /opt/ 
git clone https://github.com/SandipSingh14/Zabbix_`

#### Configure zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report according to zabbix­server (After changes ​Zabbix_​/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report/config.inc.php should look like)

`cat Zabbix_​/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report/config.inc.php`

```
<?php 
//CONFIGURABLE 
# zabbix server info(user must have API access) 
$z_server = 'http://zabbix.example.com/'; 
$z_user = 'admin'; 
$z_pass = 'zabbix'; 
# Temporary directory for storing pdf data and graphs ­ must exist 
$z_tmp_path    = './tmp'; 
# Directory for storing PDF reports 
$pdf_report_dir    = './report'; 
# Root URL to reports 
$pdf_report_url    = "./report"; 
# paper settings 
$paper_format    = 'A4'; // formats supported: 4A0, 2A0, A0 ­> A10, B0 ­> B10, C0 ­> C10, RA0 ­> RA4, SRA0 ­> SRA4, LETTER, LEGAL, EXECUTIVE, FOLIO 
$paper_orientation = 'portrait'; // formats supported: portrait / lanscape 
# time zone ­ see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php 
$timezone    = 'Asia/Calcutta'; # Logo used in PDF ­ may be empty 
# TODO: Specify image size! 
$pdf_logo    = './images/zabbix.png'; 
$company_name   = 'Zabbix'; 
//DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE 
$z_tmp_cookies     = "/tmp/"; 
$z_url_index     = $z_server ."index.php"; 
$z_url_graph    = $z_server ."chart2.php"; 
$z_url_api    = $z_server ."api_jsonrpc.php"; 
$z_login_data    = "name=" .$z_user ."&password=" .$z_pass ."&autologin=1&enter=Sign+in"; 
?>
```

- Note: Change below mentioned variables according to your zabbix server

  - z_server = http://$ZABBIX_SERVER_DOMAIN/
  - z_user = $ZABBIX_USERNAME # This user must have admin access
  - z_pass = $ZABBIX_PASSWORD
  - timezone = Asia/Calcutta # If you are in India.

#### Change directory and create directory inside zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report

`cd Zabbix_/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report 
mkdir tmp report`

#### Change zabbix auth to login method, it’s required for login into zabbix server.

`sed ­i 's,user.authenticate,user.login,g' inc/ZabbixAPI.class.php 
sed ­i 's,user.authenticate,user.login,g' inc/ZabbixAPI.class.php.org`

#### Copy zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report into /usr/share/zabbix/

`cp ­r /opt/Zabbix_/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report /usr/share/zabbix/`

#### Restart apache

`service apache2 restart`

#### Open  Generate PDF Report page

`http://zabbix.example.com/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report/index.php`

#### The page should look like this:

[image]

#### Now you can choose report type ‘HOST OR HOSTGROUP’ and click the dropdown to select the hostname or hostgroup name

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandip,
I followed all these steps, but when I hit Generate it says "Not Found"

Comment: This is what I get!

The requested URL /zabbix/zabbix-dynamic-pdf-report/report/HOSTNAME.pdf was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.10.100.122 Port 80

Comment: Also I am getting PHP errors as you could see in my question!

Comment: Hi Rijath, please check your $z_server variable and apache logs, make sure /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix­dynamic­pdf­report having zabbix user:group permission.

Comment: chmod -R 777 /usr/share/zabbix/zabbix­-dynamic-­pdf­-report
This fixed the issue! :) Thank you very much Sandip! :)

Comment: @SandipSingh Is this module still working ? I tried but it didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.