# not able to generate reports in zabbix. Error :script '/var/www/html/zabbixindex.php' not found or unable to stat

Tags: javascript, php, apache, report, zabbix

I am trying to generate reports in zabbix by using the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365129/pdf-report-generation-in-zabbix-is-not-working). Report for the graph is generated, but it is blank. Report is giving only name of the graphs, no data displayed. When I checked `/var/log/httpd/error_log` I got the following error.

> script '/var/www/html/zabbixindex.php' not found or unable to stat
>   script '/var/www/html/zabbixchart2.php' not found or unable to stat

I changed the permission for the `/usr/share/zabbix/` to 777 and owner to apache.
Does any one has any idea, how to escalate this issue?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try adding `/` after the URL to Zabbix.

Comment: I'm able to generate the pdf after changing the owner of report and temp dir to apache. Anyways thanks for the reply Richlv.

Comment: can you see the file "/var/www/html/zabbixindex.php" ?

Comment: it seems the file is not exist on your server